# Why SendNativeMessage says I try to send a 2 G byte message?

Tags: linux, firefox-addon

I try to send a message to a python3 program under Linux-Debian-Stretch-64 bits with Firefox56 Add-ons. With port.postMessage() function it works but I need to have asynchronous program so I use sendNativeMessage() but even the program works I have the message:

> Native application tried to send a message of 1990837074 bytes, which
>   exceeds the limit of 1048576 bytes.  NativeMessaging.jsm:283
>     _startRead/this.readPromise<
>   resource://gre/modules/NativeMessaging.jsm:283:11

My background program:

```
var port = browser.runtime.connectNative("gettext");
var first = 0
var portFromCS;

function onExecuted(result) {
  console.log(`appel au content-script fait`);
}

function onError(error) {
  console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}


browser.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  if (command == "toggle-feature") {
    console.log("toggling the feature!");
    var executing = browser.tabs.executeScript({ file: "/content-script.js",  allFrames: false });
    executing.then(onExecuted, onError);
  }
});

function onSend(response) {
  console.log("recu du python" + response);
}

function onBug(error) {
  console.log(`Error python: ${error}`);
}


function connected(p) {
  portFromCS = p;

  portFromCS.onMessage.addListener(function(m) {
      console.log("longueur message = " + m.length)
      if ( m.length > 1 && m.charAt(0) > 'а' && m.length < 100)  {
        var sending = browser.runtime.sendNativeMessage("gettext",m);
        sending.then(onSend, onBug);
      }
  });

}

browser.runtime.onConnect.addListener(connected);

/*
port.onMessage.addListener((response) => {
  console.log("Recu de python" + response);
});*/
```

The app code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
# Note that running python with the `-u` flag is required on Windows,
# in order to ensure that stdin and stdout are opened in binary, rather
# than text, mode.


import sys, json, struct, codecs, subprocess, pymorphy2

# Read a message from stdin and decode it.
def getMessage():
  rawLength = sys.stdin.read(4)
  if len(rawLength) == 0:
      sys.exit(0)
  messageLength = struct.unpack('@I', rawLength)[0]
  message = sys.stdin.read(messageLength)
  return json.loads(message)

# Encode a message for transmission, given its content.
def encodeMessage(messageContent):
  encodedContent = json.dumps(messageContent)
  encodedLength = struct.pack('@I', len(encodedContent))
  return {'length': encodedLength, 'content': encodedContent}

# Send an encoded message to stdout.
def sendMessage(encodedMessage):
  sys.stdout.write(encodedMessage['length'])
  sys.stdout.write(encodedMessage['content'])
  sys.stdout.flush()

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

while True:
    receivedMessage = ""
    receivedMessage = getMessage()
```

The content-script:

```
var selectedText = getSelection().toString();

var myPort = browser.runtime.connect({name:"port-from-cs"});

myPort.postMessage(selectedText);
```

Manifest.json:

```
{

  "description": "Native messaging and Hotkey and content-script messaging",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "getSelectedTextFromHotkey",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/message.svg"
  },

  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "gettext@example.org",
      "strict_min_version": "50.0"
    }
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "commands": {
  "toggle-feature": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Ctrl+Shift+4",
      "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+5"
    },
    "description": "Send the selected text"
  }
},


  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/message.svg"
  },

 "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content-script.js"]
  }

  ],

  "permissions": [ "<all_urls>","nativeMessaging","webRequest"]

}
```

The program of python gives the correct informations and don't send information to the background program. So, I think the problem comes from the background.js

Do you know where is the error ?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Given that the error is at least claiming that it's your native application that send the large amount of data, we're going to need that too (as source code).

Comment: my app don't send a message

Comment: I had the same issue (3 hours trying to solve it) turns out that in my case, I was printing the logs into the console. If the code is exactly as you put it, I don't see logs... meaning that it's not what happened to me. If you put just the example and in your actual code you are printing things to the screen, that's what's wrong. I know that this might be too late but if it helps, it costs me nothing. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never.

Because your application doesn't reply a message, Firefox reads the entire stdin buffer (or something) searching for a valid response message. The buffer it reads exceeds the maximum size (and is probably determined by your OS). Since it still doesn't find a valid message Firefox assumes that the application has sent an enormous message and throws an error.

This can also be caused by responding with invalid messages.

Solution: Reply with a valid message (i.e. encoded with `encodeMessage` and sent with `sendMessage`)